# Modifying bits in a byte with a class

Tags: c++, bitset

I want to directly modify a bit in a byte.

In GCC, you can do it as follow:

```cpp
struct virtualByte {
    unsigned char b0 : 1;
    unsigned char b1 : 1;
    unsigned char b2 : 1;
    unsigned char b3 : 1;
    unsigned char b4 : 1;
    unsigned char b5 : 1;
    unsigned char b6 : 1;
    unsigned char b7 : 1;
} __attribute__((__packed__));

#define sbit(_byte, _pos) (((volatile struct virtualByte *)&_byte)->b ## _pos)
```

Usage:

```cpp
unsigned char myByte = 0x00;

#define firstBit sbit(myByte, 0)

firstBit = 1; // Implicit myByte |= 0x01;
```

To make things neater I want to have class that does this for me. I came up with the following concept:

```cpp
unsigned char myByteRef = 0x00;

Byte myByte(&myByteRef);

myByte[0] = 1; // Implicit myByteRef |= 0x01;

fprintf(stderr, "%2.2X\n", myByteRef);
```

But this does not work because in c++ you cannot return a reference to a single bit. Overloading the constructor does not work either.

Is there a possibility to implement such behaviour? The assignment operator should directly modify its underlying byte (not a set of bytes).

Comment: See C++'s [`bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: I know there is C++'s `bitset` but I want to directly modify the bits in a byte.

Comment: Side note: The first method is not portable between Big-Endian and Little-Endian architectures, because the designated compilers typically interpret the bit-field order in opposite manners.

Comment: No problem, here's how it could be implemented https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/bitset

Comment: @doc This isn't helpful at all.

Comment: You want basically implement `bitset`. So you can check how they have done this.

Comment: @doc No that is not what I want. As you can see in my question, I want to access the bits through the array operator, not through bitwise operators.

Comment: Read docs in class `reference` - "This encapsulates the concept of a single bit..." then you have `reference operator[](size_t __position)` - "Array-indexing support." C++ reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/operator%5B%5D/

Comment: @doc Yeah, and now tell me how to return a reference to a single bit!

Comment: Read the docs on class `reference` -> https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/bitset#L787  "This encapsulates the concept of a single bit. An instance of this class is a proxy for an actual bit; this way the individual bit operations are done as faster word-size bitwise instructions."

Comment: @doc I am sorry, I got it now, thank you very much!

Comment: NP. BTW There are no references to single bits, because CPUs operate on words as their natural units. Therefore word or byte is picked as smallest addresable unit. As address space was a problem for 8, 16 and even 32 bit computers (addresable RAM limit) It would be a waste to include bit position in the address.

Comment: You can access individual bits in an integral data type by using the binary `&` (*AND*) and the binary `|` (*OR*).  Search the web for "masking bits example c++".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yeah, I already know that xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally came to a solution, many thanks to @doc!

My solution:

```cpp
class Bit {
    private:
        volatile uint8_t    *byte;
        uint8_t             bitPos;

    public:
        Bit(void)
        {
        }

        void init(volatile uint8_t *const byte, uint8_t const bitPos)
        {
            this->byte      = byte;
            this->bitPos    = (bitPos > 7u ? 7u : bitPos);
        }

        void setValue(bool const bitValue)
        {
            if (!this->byte) return;

            if (bitValue) {
                *this->byte |=  (1u << this->bitPos);
            } else {
                *this->byte &= ~(1u << this->bitPos);
            }
        }
};

class BitReference {
    private:
        Bit         &ref;

    public:
        BitReference(Bit &ref) : ref(ref)
        {
        }

        void operator=(bool const bitValue)
        {
            this->ref.setValue(bitValue);
        }
};

class Byte {
    private:
        Bit         bits[8];

    public:
        Byte(volatile uint8_t *const byte)
        {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
                this->bits[i].init(byte, i);
            }
        }

        /* This did the trick :)! */
        BitReference operator[](size_t index)
        {
            if (index > 7) index = 7;

            return BitReference(this->bits[index]);
        }
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
uint8_t myPort = 0x00;

int main(int const argc, const char **const argv)
{
    Byte abc(&myPort);

    abc[0] = 1;
    abc[1] = 1;
    abc[2] = 1;
    abc[3] = 1;

    fprintf(stderr, "%2.2X\n", myPort);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset):

```
std::bitset<12> someBits; // 12 bits
someBits[0] = true; // set 1st bit
std::cout << someBits.count() << '\n'; // prints 1

std::bitset<12>::reference bit5 = someBits[5];
bit5 = true;
std::cout << someBits.count() << '\n'; // prints 2
```

You can use the [index operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at) to return a reference to a bit in the way you want. Note that this reference is not a `bool&` but rather a `std::bitset::reference`: